# Textmate: regular expression to replace matches preserving case?

Tags: macos, find, regex, textmate, find-and-replace

How can I use a single search / replace to replace all words `town` with `village` preserving the case of the first letter in this sentence:

```
Towns are small cities. I live in a town.
```

[image]

Comment: Un-check the ignore-case and do several replacements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\b(?:(T)|t)own(s?)\b` → `(?1:\u)village$2`

(And uncheck ignore case in the dialog)

- `\b` = word boundary
- `(?:)` = non-capturing group
- `(?1:\u)` = if captured group 1 then convert next character to uppercase

Comment: This is way smarter than mine, def the way to go

Comment: If I could give you more than one upvote I would.

Comment: Very cool. Is this regular Perl regexp syntax?

Comment: @DanielBeck No, TextMate uses the [oniguruma](http://geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt) library. [Perl 5](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) seems to support `\u`, but not `(?1:)`.

Comment: Thanks for the link (it requires `www.` though)!

Comment: @DanielBeck Old but might be useful for someone else: [oniguruma](https://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions) rules

Answer (score 2):

I'm on my work machine right now, so no TextMate here for me to test on, but i think this *might* do what you want:

```
Find:     \b(T)?((?<!T)t)?(?<! )own(s)?\b
Replace:  (?1:Village)(?2:village)$3
```

(Make sure to untick 'Ignore case' first.)

Explanation:

The 'Find' pattern searches for the letters `own` preceded by a `T` or a `t`, and then captures them to `$1` and `$2` respectively. The `(?<!T)` inside the second capture makes sure that you don't get both of them at the same time (like `Tt` together), as unlikely as that probably is, and the `(?<! )` bit means that `own` can't be preceded by a space — this should prevent it from matching the word `own` by itself. The `\b` on either side means that it should only match the whole word (otherwise it will match things like `townies` and `chown`). Lastly, the `(s)?` part captures a final `s` (if it exists) to `$3`.

The replace pattern uses [conditional insertions](http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions#conditional_insertions) to determine what to replace the text by. In pseudo-code the replace string says basically:

```
if (the first capture [T] exists)  { replace the text by the word Village }
if (the second capture [t] exists) { replace the text by the word village }
```

(And then it adds `$3`, which will either be empty or contain an `s`)

It's ugly, but i think it will probably work for the example you gave anyway.

Comment: That deletes `\bown\b` where the first `\b` isn't a space.

Comment: Ah. I guess that is what happens when you don't test things :(